# Xcode UIWebView with SQLite Database

Tags: jquery, database, xcode, sqlite, uiwebview

I'm creating an iPhone app that uses UIWebView, I have a MySQL database with 7 tables and about 100 rows in each table. I want to avoid using PHP so that I can locally load the html file into my app using:

```
[myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

rather than an external URL...

I've exported the MySQL database, and formatted all the information into a SQLite database.

Is there a way to add the database into my Xcode project, and then query the data into my HTML file without having access to the internet?

Clarification, is there a localized, offline alternative to:

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
$variable = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name");
?>
```

Essentially, I'm looking for an ALL jQuery approach so that my application doesn't require internet!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that comes across this post, I ended up using `.getJSON()` with a local `.json` file.

I included the json file with:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></scipt>`

and then used the `getJSON` calls where needed! It works perfectly without internet!